# Problem with assigning a pointer to Location in TextAdventur Game

Tags: c++, game-development

So currently I am trying to make a simple text adventure game in c++ but I got stuck on a problem.I am trying to connect all locations to make a list of possible areas players can visit but I can't remember how to fix this little problem

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TfP62.png)
I know this is a very basic question but I really need to sort this out quickly

```
#include "Player.h"
#include "Location.h"
#include "MainMenu.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    
    Location FirstLevel(1, "Abondend Farm", "FirstChalenge",
         &SecondLevel, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);

    Location SecondLevel(2, "SecondLevel", "SecondChalenge",
        nullptr, &FirstLevel, nullptr, nullptr);

    Player player(&FirstLevel);
    MainMenu menu(&player);

    menu.MenuOptions();
    

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In C++ everything needs to be at least declared to exist before you can use it. Think on it this way, how can you have the address of `SecondLevel` before `SecondLevel` exists?

Comment: Path of least resistance is probably to use a setter or similar function to link the floors together after they're all constructed.

Comment: ok all done thank you

Comment: Off-topic:  "Abondend" --> "Abandoned"; "Chalenge" --> "Challenge"